# volume shadow copy won't stay disabled

Tags: volume-shadow-copy, vss

· i disabled **volume shadow copy** from **services** > **properties**

· yet, it keeps auto-re-enabling

· i then re-named **vssadmin.exe** to **vssad.exe** from C:\Windows\System32\

· but this didn't stop shadow copies from being created

· i see that other folders also have a **vssadmin.exe**

· but windows prevents me from re-naming those files

? why might **vssadmin.exe** be auto-re-enabling

? and how can i stop shadow copies from being created

Comment: The only (built-in) thing in Windows that creates shadow copies on consumer systems is System Restore.

Comment: Unclear. What's the problem with shadow copies? How did you disable them? Where do you see these shadow copies?

Comment: @harrymc · apparently, this was due to system restore allocation being set to 100% · i changed it to 1% now

Comment: @DanielB ·ah, system restore allocation was set to 100% · i changed it to 1% now · this seems to have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System restore allocation was set to 100%. Changing it to 1% seems to have fixed it.

[image]